# Laravel. Cron work only 1 time

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, time, cron

I tried to start cron in Laravel, what writo time ( `Log::info(time()."\r\n");`) to log file. I made next steps in console -
[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCIaH.png)

It worked, but only for once, for adding the cron I have put the following code in schedule file

```
$schedule->command('command:addToDB')->everyMinute();
```

My handle function looks like

```
public function handle()
{
    Log::info(time()."\r\n");
}
```

Can somebody help me with this problem?

Comment: Did you add this line to your crontab? * * * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1

Comment: @ThànhChungBùi  yes, you can see it at image in my post

Comment: no, i mean did you add new record to crontab (execute crontab -e and  copy the above line to)

Comment: @ThànhChungBùi when I write crontab -e  , console write me next -

Comment: * * * * * php /Users/MacUser/work/domains/shop/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
                                                                             
"/tmp/crontab.TOoq2skYRB" 1L, 86C

Answer (score 0):

First of all your question had hell of mistakes from typos to grammar 
Secondly, have you followed the steps given in [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling#scheduling-artisan-commands) read the docs and follow the steps thoroughly.

and as mentioned by Thanh you have to add scheduler first like this

```
* * * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

if everything is fine then check your path there must be some mistake in it.

Comment: whats happening I will try to help you

Comment: Pyraimid      I already had 1 cron. I need to start him. when i write to console " php artisan schedule:run" to start cron - it work, but only 1 time. I have everyMinute() cron, but it work only 1 time,at the moment when I write this command

Comment: you need to write that command in `crontab -e` the command I have posted in answer

Comment: I done it, and then console write me - "* * * * * php /Users/MacUser/work/domains/shop/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1"

Comment: shop is your project name?

Comment: Im stupid) It was incorrect way to my project. Now it work. Thanks for help)